# string-substitute* not working

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I am trying following code:

```
(require-extension srfi-13)
(require-extension regex)
(print (string-substitute* "This is a test" '(("a test" . "NO TESTING ZONE" ) ) ) )
```

It works, with following output:

```
This is NO TESTING ZONE
```

But following does not work:

```
(print (string-substitute* "This is a test" '(("a test" . (string-append "NO " "TESTING") ) ) ) )
```

Following is the error:

```
Error: (string-substitute) bad argument type - not a string: (string-append "NO " "TESTING")
```

Even though, following shows that the output is indeed a string:

```
(print (string? (string-append "NO " "TESTING")))
#t
```

Where is the problem and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `string-substitute*`.

You're quoting the list, so `(string-append "NO " "TESTING")` is not evaluated:

```
> '(("a test" . (string-append "NO " "TESTING")))
'(("a test" string-append "NO " "TESTING"))
```

Use quasiquote:

```
`(("a test" . ,(string-append "NO " "TESTING")
```

or don't quote at all:

```
(list (cons "a test" (string-append "NO " "TESTING"))
```

Comment: Why this does not work: `(print (string-substitute* "this is a test" (list (list "a test" "NO TESTING ZONE" ) (list "this"  "THIS"))))`

Comment: @rnso Because it wants a list of pairs where both the car and the cdr are strings, not ones where the car is a string and the cdr is a list.